# How to show time value based on user's time zone using Django template tags

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I'm saving all timing to my database in 'UTC' time zone, but I want every user to see this value converted to his own timezone. is it possible to be used in Django?

my **settings.py** :

```py
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Here is what I tried:

```
{% load tz %}
<p>
Leave on {{ request.date_time.date|localtime }}  at {{ request.date_time.time|localtime }}
</p>
```

But it gives me a blank result, and when I remove the `|localtime` part, it shows it in the UTC format. any help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localtime` template tag does not operate on `date` object. It operates on `datetime` object. You should apply it on datetime object and then chain with date filter.

```
{{ request.date_time|localtime|date:'Y-m-d' }} at {{ request.date_time|localtime|date:'H:i' }}
```

Or you can do

```
{% with local=request.date_time|localtime %}
  <p>
    Leave on {{ local|date:'Y-m-d' }} at {{ local|date:'H:i' }}
  </p>
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert your `timezone` into the user's `timezone` from `Django` `view` and pass it in `context` and use that `context` in your `template` as below...

**views.py**

```
from django.utils import timezone
local_time = timezone.localtime(your_datetime_object)
```

Now, you can pass `local_time` into your context and use it in your template.

For more reference, you can [click here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/utils/timezone.py#L298)

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_publish_timezone(self):
    import pytz
    return self.publish.astimezone(pytz.timezone(self.author.get_timezone_str())).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

here `get_timezone_str()` is the one who convert `id` of timezone to string like '`Asia/Kolkata`'

```
def get_timezone_str(self):
    from .timezone import from_system
    try:
        return from_system[self.timezone]
    except KeyError:
        return 'UTC'
```

`from_system` is `dict` some demos are below.

```
from_system = {0: 'America/Puerto_Rico',
1: 'America/New_York',
2: 'America/Chicago',
3: 'America/Denver',
}
```